# have this black area in basement against thebase of a concrete block . It was slightly damp . Any ideas or suggestions on cause

Tags: plumbing, water, basement, mold, water-damage

have this black area in basement against the base of a concrete block .It was slightly damp .A few  surrounding items are also kind of damp. It’s been raining today and I only just now noticed it, so I don’t really know how long it’s been going on. Any ideas or suggestions on cause / solutions?

[image: Image of the damp area]

Comment: what is behind the wall

Comment: Mold from water intrusion?